# Selecting column RDD scala-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, error-handling, rdd

I need to do the following operation: selecting each field in the rdd.
I have to convert it in Scala, expecially the part in the third line, selecting each column:

```
val rddHash=x.map(row =>(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(row(0).toString.getBytes("UTF-8")),row(1).toString)).reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a+b))
val z=rddHash.cartesian(rddHash)
val outRdd=z.map(m => (m(0)(0),(m(1)(0),euclidean(m(0)(1).split(','),m(1)(1).split(',')))))
```

X is the dataset charged as (String,Object).

But this code doesn't work, the problem is the part related to the third lines in which I try to select elements via m(0)(0),m(1)(0) and so on.
The error is :

```
<console>:42: error: ((String, String), (String, String)) does not take parameters
```

How can I select each field in the rdd in Scala?

Ps my code line in pyspark is the following one:

```
outRdd=cartesian.map(lambda m: (m[0][0],(m[1][0],euclidean(m[0][1].split(','),m[1][1].split(',')))))
```

Where cartesian have the same struucture showed before:

```
((String, String), (String, String))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly call `m(index)` on tuples in scala.

You can either access fields using `_1` or using pattern matching, which is usually more readable:

```
val outRdd = z.map(m => (m._1._1, (m._2._1, ...))
```

Or:

```
val outRdd = z.map { case ((hex1, obj1), (hex2, obj2)) =>
  (hex1, (hex2, ... ))
}
```